# Failing to calculate the gradient and y-shift for best fit line using sum-squares method. Can anyone help me to pinpoint the issue?

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I'm trying to work out how to make the working implementation of fitting the straight line among the set data points. I base my function:

```rust
pub fn sum_squares<Q: CanBeLabel>(l1: &Line<Q>, accuracy: u32) -> Point {

    let mut dataset_size: f32 = 0.;
    let (mut y_mean, mut x_mean): (f32, f32) = (0., 0.);
    let (mut y_max, mut x_max): (f32, f32) = (0., 0.);

    for point in l1.points() {
        dataset_size += 1.;
        y_mean += point.y;
        x_mean += point.x;

        if y_max < point.y {
            y_max = point.y;
        }

        if x_max < point.x {
            x_max = point.x;
        }
    }

    y_mean /= dataset_size;
    x_mean /= dataset_size;

    let fpa = |a: f32, b: f32| -> f32 {
        2. * dataset_size * a * x_mean * x_mean + 2. * dataset_size * x_mean * b - 2. * dataset_size * y_mean * x_mean
    };

    let fpb = |a: f32, b: f32| -> f32 {
        - (a * dataset_size * y_mean) + 2. * a * k * x_mean + 2. * dataset_size * b
    };

    let fpa2 = |b: f32| -> f32 { 2. * dataset_size * x_mean  };

    let fpb2 = |a: f32| -> f32 { 2. * dataset_size  };

    let mut a: f32 = y_max;
    let mut b: f32 = y_max;

    for _ in 0..accuracy {
        a -=  ( fpa(a, b) / fpa2(b));
        b -= (fpb(a, b) / fpb2(a));

    }

    return Point::new(a, b);
}
```

I base my function on the following expansion:

$\sum^{k}_{n = 1}\left(y_n-\left(ax_n+b\right)\right)^2=$

$\sum^{k}_{n = 1}{{(y}_n^2-2y_n\left(ax_n+b\right)+\left(ax_n+b\right)^2)}=$

$\sum^{k}_{n = 1}\left(y_n^2\ -2y_nax_n-2y_nb+a^2{x_n}^2+2a^2x_nb+b^2\right)=$

$k\bar{y^2}\ -2k\bar{y}ax-2k\bar{y}b+{a^2k\bar{x}}^2+2a^2k\bar{x}b+kb^2$

and then take derivatives with respect to a, and b:

a. $0\ -\ 2k\bar{y}x\ -\ 0+{\ 2ak\bar{x}}^2\ +\ 4ak\bar{x}b\ \ +\ 0\ \equiv{\ 2ak\bar{x}}^2\ +\ \ 4ak\bar{x}b\ -\ 2k\bar{y}x$

b. $0\ -\ 0\ -\ 2k\bar{y}b\ +\ 0\ +\ 2a^2k\bar{x}b\ +\ kb^2\ \equiv2a^2k\bar{x}\ +\ 2kb\ -\ 2k\bar{y}b$

and then approximating the zeroes of the derivative via Newton-Raphson (so I also use second derivatives, where $2k\bar{x}^2 + 4k\bar{x}b$ is with respect to a and $2k - 2k\bar{y}$ with respect to b).

However when I plot my graph for a dataset consisting of 4 points where $x \in [1,4] \land x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y = x + 666$,

```rust
fn make_dataset() -> Line<String> {
    let mut ret: Line<String> = Line::new("Cats".to_owned());

    for i in 0..5 {
        ret.add_point(Point::new(i as f32, i as f32 + 7_f32));
    }

    ret
}
```

and for checking:

```python
def make_line(a: float, b: float, xs: range):
    x, y = [], []
    for i in xs:
        x.append(i), y.append(a + 666)

    return x, y
```

for every pair of consequetive x values graph looks like so:

for odd x's:
[image]

for even x's:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @gnasher729, I did not check your code nor your equations, which seem overly complicated. An explicit solution is

$$a=\frac{\sum_k (y_k-\overline y)(x_k-\overline x)}{\sum_k (x-\overline x)^2}$$

and

$$b=\overline y-a\overline x.$$

---

**Explanation:**

Note that by linearity (or by differentiating the global error on $b$),

$$\overline y=a\overline x+b$$ allows to eliminate $b$ and reduce the problem to the minimization of

$$\sum_k(\hat y_k-a\hat x_k)^2$$ where the hat denotes centered variables. After differentiation on $a$,

$$\sum_k\hat y_k\hat x_k-a\sum_k\hat x_k^2=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I really don't want to go and debug your code. But if you want a linear approximation by arbitrary functions $f_i$ minimising the squares of errors, you create a system of linear equations, with the coefficients on the left side being the sums of $f_i \cdot f_j$, and on the right side you write the sums of $f_i \cdot y$. You solve the system and that's it.

Accordingly, for approximation by two functions $f_1(x) = x$ and $f_2(x) = 1$ you create a system of two linear equations in two variables, with the four coefficients on the left side being the sums of x^2, x, x and 1, and the numbers on the right side being the sums of $x \cdot y$ and $1 \cdot y$.

This is all just linear algebra and linear equations, so using Newton-Raphson seems quite bizarre.